# For each element in javascript array, add to select html, then remove on change

Tags: javascript, jquery

Essentially I'm trying to display a second "select" block when a certain option is chosen from the first select block if the value matches. If this does occur, the second select options will be populated from a javascript array.

I've managed to complete the first step, however I'm struggling with the second step. Using append will work fine providing the option isn't changed again, otherwise it appends more array values to the options.

**Html:**

```
<select class='upload_location' name='upload_location'>
    <option value="home" selected="selected">Home</option>
    <option value="contact">Contact</option>
    <option value="blog">Blog</option>
</select>

<div class='picture_slider' style='display:none;'>
    <select name='sub_dir' class='sub_dir'>
    // Add elements here
    </select>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".upload_location").change(function(){

        if ($(this).val() == "contact") {
            $('.picture_slider').show();
            var arr = ['element_01', 'element_02']
        } else if ($(this).val() == "blog") {
            $('.picture_slider').show();
            var arr = ['place_01', 'place_02']
        }

        for (var index = 0; index < arr.length; ++index) {
          $(".sub_dir").append("<option value='"+arr[index]+"'>"+arr[index]+"</option>");
        }

    });
</script>
```

Here's an example of how it currently works:
http://jsfiddle.net/G8rdL/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
var $subdir = $(".sub_dir");
$(".upload_location").change(function () {
    var arr, location = $(this).val();

    if ($(this).val() == "contact") {
        arr = ['element_01', 'element_02']
    } else if ($(this).val() == "blog") {
        arr = ['place_01', 'place_02']
    }

    $('.picture_slider').toggle(!!arr);
    $subdir.empty()

    if(arr){
        for (var index = 0; index < arr.length; ++index) {
            $subdir.append("<option value='" + arr[index] + "'>" + arr[index] + "</option>");
        }
    }

});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/uKyt8/)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [empty()](http://api.jquery.com/empty/) to remove values in it, before appending the new values:

```
$(".sub_dir").empty();

for (var index = 0; index < arr.length; ++index) {
    $(".sub_dir").append("<option value='"+arr[index]+"'>"+arr[index]+"</option>");
 }
```

Demo [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/G8rdL/2/)